# File Uploading without page refresh in Web pages

Tags: asp.net

Hii,

Any one knows how to upload files to the physical location of the server. It is possible using file upload control that i know. But i want to avoid the external postbacking of the page. For e.g exactly like what in the yahoo mail did.

In yahoo mail latest version if you attach a file that won't post back and attach that file in to server. What is the technology behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you submit a form it does a POST request to the server, causing a refresh. Ajax requests get round this by using JavaScript to send the POST data through to the server, and that doesn't need a page refresh.

Ajax requests can't be used to send file data though, so the best way to currently do it is with an iframe hack - you use JavaScript to dynamically build up a form within an iframe, submit that form via JavaScript, and listen for the iframe's onload event. So you know when the form has been submitted. A version of this approach is detailed here:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

Other methods to do this would include using a Flash-based solution like http://www.swfupload.org/ or a wrapper like http://www.plupload.com/ - these will prevent you having to roll your own solution and will also provide some extra functionality - upload progress feedback, for example.